# Using unity xml config to register an interface with nested generics

Tags: c#, xml, generics, unity-container

If I have a class that implements a generic interface it works fine to configure it using the unity xml config.

```
public interface IReader<T> { }

public class Fund { }

public class FundReader : IReader<Fund> { }
```

and the unity xml:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <namespace name="System.ComponentModel" />
  <namespace name="TestUnityIssue" />
  <assembly name="TestUnityIssue" />
  <container>
    <register type="IReader[Fund]" mapTo="FundReader" />
  </container>
</unity>
```

And this works just using the following code:

```
var container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
var fundReader = container.Resolve<IReader<Fund>>();
```

However, in some cases there is a wrapper around the type used in the reader. For example, adding the following two classes:

```
public class Wrapper<T> { }

public class WrappedFundReader : IReader<Wrapper<Fund>> { }
```

and if I add the following to the unity config:

```
<register type="IReader[Wrapper[Fund]]" mapTo="WrappedFundReader" />
```

and then try to resolve it using:

```
var wrappedReader = container.Resolve<IReader<Wrapper<Fund>>>();
```

I get the following exception:

```
InvalidOperationException - The current type,
TestUnityIssue.IReader`1[TestUnityIssue.Wrapper`1[TestUnityIssue.Fund]],
is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
mapping?
```

I can get around this by configuring it using code instead of xml:

```
container.RegisterType<IReader<Wrapper<Fund>>, WrappedFundReader>();
```

or I can create an interface that goes between and use that instead:

```
public interface IWrappedReader<T> : IReader<Wrapper<T>> { }

public class WrappedFundReader : IWrappedReader<Fund>
```

and the config would change to:

```
<register type="IWrappedReader[Fund]" mapTo="WrappedFundReader" />
```

It will still give me an instance that I can cast to `IReader<Wrapper<Fund>>`, but it seems like I should be able to make this work with the unity config.

What am I missing to make this work?

(If also tried creating specific aliases and wasn't able to get that to work either)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aliasing worked for me...

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="WrappedFund" type="TestUnityIssue.Wrapper`1[[TestUnityIssue.Fund, TestUnityIssue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], TestUnityIssue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <namespace name="TestUnityIssue" />
    <assembly name="TestUnityIssue" />
    <container>
        <register type="IReader[Fund]" mapTo="FundReader" />
        <register type="IReader[WrappedFund]" mapTo="WrappedFundReader" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

these both resolved...

```
var fundReader = container.Resolve<IReader<Fund>>();
var wrappedReader = container.Resolve<IReader<Wrapper<Fund>>>();
```

and depending on your situation, you may be able to get away with less than the full AssemblyQualifiedName...

```
<alias alias="WrappedFund" type="TestUnityIssue.Wrapper`1[[TestUnityIssue.Fund, TestUnityIssue]], TestUnityIssue" />
```

Comment: Great solution! I had tried a few aliases but never one for the wrapped fund, works great! Thanks!