# Unity 2.X Design Time Generic Registration

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am using **Unity 2.1.505.2** (Windows 7, .NET 4.0)

I have an interface `IRepository<T, K>`

I have a class `ExampleRepo : IRepository<IEnumerable<SomeDto>, OtherDto>`

What is the correct Design Time code for registration (**XML**)?

I have tried the following in my **unity.config**:

`<register type="IRepository[[IEnumerable[SomeDto]], [OtherDto]]" mapTo="ExampleRepo" />`

This does not work.  Gives an error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [23795215](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795215/using-unity-xml-config-to-register-an-interface-with-nested-generics/23796661#23796661)

Comment: @TylerOhlsen saw this earlier today and the specified solution worked.  I still have to try fully qualifying the types in the type registration without an alias.  But yes, good searching. Took me forever to find that one.